# C++ /CLI padding of DataGridView DefaultCellStyle

Tags: c++, datagridview, c++-cli, padding

I would like to change my `cellpadding` on a `CellMouseEnter` event.
I thought it would be pretty straightforward.

```
System::Void dgv_CellMouseEnter(System::Object^ sender, 
                           System::Windows::Forms::DataGridViewCellEventArgs^  e) {
    dgv->Rows[e->RowIndex]->DefaultCellStyle->Padding =gcnew 
    System::Windows::Forms::Padding(5);
}
```

**but I get an error**

```
funktion "System::Windows::Forms::DataGridViewCellStyle::Padding::set" cannot 
be called with the given argument list. Argument types are: 
(System::Windows::Forms::Padding ^)
object type is :System::Windows::Forms::DataGridViewCellStyle^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Padding property(set) does not accept pointer type.

Try by removing `gcnew` (working).

```
dgv->Rows[e->RowIndex]->DefaultCellStyle->Padding  =  System::Windows::Forms::Padding(5);
```